# lodash find multiple properties and merge result

Tags: javascript, lodash

Using last version of lodash, I would like to know how to find by multiple properties and merge similar objects. Here is an example:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John",
    "function": "student"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "David",
    "function": "teacher"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John",
    "function": null
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John",
    "function": "student"
  }
]
```

In this case, I would like to obtain:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John",
    "function": "student"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "David",
    "function": "teacher"
  }
]
```

Similar objects have been deleted and similar objects with two properties ("id" and "name") which are equals have been merged.

Any solution to do that ? For many objects which are equivalents, I would like to keep the object which is the most deep filled.

Thank you in advance ! :)

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`uniqBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniqBy).

```js
var arr = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John",
    "function": "student"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "David",
    "function": "teacher"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John",
    "function": null
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John",
    "function": "student"
  }
];

var newArr = _.uniqBy(arr, 'name');
console.log(newArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I already tried this solution and it's not working, if I'm setting null to the first occurrence of John, the "function" field is not override by others values, and that's the point of my question here.